# In rust, why does s[0..] returns a type of `str`?

Tags: rust

In my understanding, `s[0..]` calls the method ops::Index::index. I try to call `s.index(0..)`, but find that it returns a type of `&str`. The code is as follows

```rust
let a = String::from("hello world");
let b = &a;
let c = b.index(1..);
println!("{}", c);
let d = b[1..];
println!("{}", d);
```

This code will display an error, and indicate that the variable `d` is of type `str`.

What do I understand wrong? and how to understand the `[]` and `index()` in rust?

Comment: what else would you want its return ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation of [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html), we find:

> `container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)`

and

> This allows nice things such as `let value = v[index]` if the type of `value` implements `Copy`.

In your example, `c` has type `&str` as you expect, but `d` would be the dereference (`*`) of such an `&str`; this would lead to `str` which is rejected by the compiler (not sized).

In order to obtain a `&str` in `d`, you could write:

```rust
let d = &b[1..]; // & was missing
```

which is really explicit because it clearly states: *«I want to **refer to** something which stands inside `b`»*.

Here is another example of the implicit dereference (`*`) in a different context:

```rust
let mut arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let n = arr[1]; // not *arr[1]
arr[2] += n; // not *arr[2]
println!("{:?}", arr); // [1, 2, 5, 4]
```